# Can I use existing metro classes to create a bindable string not connected to a visible ui control

Tags: data-binding, windows-8

I am writing a windows 8 app (for myself) that generates g-code for some auto generated paths. When generating the g-code I want to use textual templates that can be written and edited by myself within the app. I thought it would be a good idea to follow the {binding path} notation so my template might look something like

"{binding Gcode.LinearMove} {binding Axis.X} {binding CurrentPoint.X } ....   "   to give
"G1 X 90 ... " after databinding.

All the objects Gcode, Axis, CurrentPoint could be defined to be part of the DataContext of the code generator.

I currently use simple strings built using StringBuilder and passed to a ListView for display and use format to replace the values, but of course this freezes the properties I use in code and is restrictive. I have played with specific template names which were replaced using regular expressions but again the replacement values were frozen in code.

I thought that using editable templates would allow me much greater freedom to dynamically choose which properties to use at run time.

So my question, 
Is this possible to do using existing metro classes and the .net implementation of data binding or do I have to start from scratch? Bearing in mind that the binding will be on non visible and non UI controls. I thought that using Textblocks for lists of thousands of lines of gcode would be a silly thing to do in terms of resources and also I read somewhere that multibinding was unavailable in apps.

Alan

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use either TextBlock or RichTextBlock and bind individual Runs to the properties you want to display. When the code behind changes (as long as it implements INotifyPropertyChange correctly) then the text on the screen should update as expected.

Here's a good little article on binding runs:

http://tozon.info/blog/post/2012/10/16/Windows-Store-apps-the-case-of-missing-StringFormat-or-Binding-on-the-Run.aspx

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport

Comment: Thanks, I tried using runs as you suggested only I do not know how to databind to the run text property in c#. I set the text directly to something like {binding mypath} that that did not seem to execute. When I looked at the textBlocks text property it just echoed the binding text. Run doesnt seem to have an accessible SetBinding call and Runs do not have a public TextProperty  property. So any hints as to how to proceed?